# How do I get the x,y coordinates of selected text on a webpage?

Tags: python, find, return, coordinates, html

I have a simple find function that will find what is passed to it on the webpage. I then need to return the x,y coordinates of where the found text is located on that page.

```
def find_text():
    win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0)
    win32api.keybd_event(ord('F'), 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    win32api.keybd_event(ord('F'), 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY |        win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
    win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_CONTROL, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

Comment: Correction, this function turns find on, I then use my paste function to paste in what it is finding

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to write some sort of automation... I think you would be better off using a web automation framework like [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/free-testing-framework.aspx) or [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). If you are trying to get the coordinates to click, there is no need with frameworks like these, you just have to invoke a `click` function usually.

Comment: Unfortunately Click cannot be used until after I have the X,Y coordinates as what I am "finding" is randomly displayed to different locations on the page each time the page is refreshed. I do plan on using click once I have the coordinates.What I am searching for also is not displayed in the source code for the page.

Comment: So then it is ajax? Those frameworks handle ajax. While it may not be visible by using the browser's "View Source" if it is showing up and able to be searched for using the browser's "Find" then it is in the DOM tree (I can't think of a way for it to not be).

Comment: They can also easily get the coordinates of things. See the last example [here](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/user-guide/getting-started/automating-browser-actions.aspx). Also, if you have Chrome or Firefox, try using Inspect Element or Developer Tools to view the source instead of using the "View Source" option, and you should be able to see the elements in realtime as they are manipulated by javascript.

Comment: thanks I think I'm headed back in the right direction, I appreciate the help!

Comment: it appears the text i am searching for is included in a <map> tag that is included in the main source

Comment: You should still be able to access it with the frameworks. If not, there are also other ways of automating. If it is a link, you can parse the page for it, then redirect to it manually. Using the browser to find it with keyboard shortcuts is not ideal.